# How to call up a window only once with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to know if there is any other way to call up a window once and not to call the desired window over again. This is the code I used :

```
void secondWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    MainWindow *mainwindow;
    mainwindow = new MainWindow(this);
    mainwindow->show();
}
```

When you click the `pushButton`, it keeps on reproducing a new window. So is there a way it can show the same MainWindow whenever the pushButton is clicked?

Comment: instead of create a new MainWindow try mainwindow = QApplication::activeWindow() it should retour your current window.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this problem in one of the following ways:

1) Disable the `pushButton` button once it is clicked, and the `MainWindow` is created,

2) Declare the pointer to `MainWindow` as a `secondWindow` class' member variable:

```
class secondWindow : public ...
{
public:
    secondWindow()
    {
        m_mainWindow = new MainWindow(this);
    }

private slots:
    void secondWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        m_mainwindow->show();
    }
private:
    MainWindow *m_mainWindow;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will do what you want

```
void secondWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    static MainWindow* mainwindow = new MainWindow(this);
    mainwindow->show();
    mainwindow->raise();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for giving your contribution they really helped

Answer (score 0):

You should only initialize a new object once. Otherwise you only have to display the Window object.

```
class MainWindowFactory {
    private:
        MainWindow* mainWindow;
    public:
        MainWindowFactory();
        MainWindow* getMainWindow();
};

MainWindowFactory::MainWindowFactory() {
    mainWindow = NULL;
}

MainWindow* MainWindowFactory::getMainWindow() {
    if (!mainWindow) {
        mainWindow = new MainWindow(this);
    }
    mainWindow->show();
}
```